# Utilizar target con dos elementos con la misma id CSS

Tags: html, css

tengo un menú con dos ul uno que es las opciones del menu y el otro es el contexto de la opcion lo único es que utilizo target a las opciones para que el usuario sepa en cual opción esta ( utilizo la misma id para el contexto de la opción y para las opciones ) Y para el contexto lo que hago es ocultar los demás li y mostrar el li con la id de la opcion.

El problema es que no me muestra el contexto. ¿como podría hacer, Existe alguna Alternativa a target?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte hace falta ver un [mcve] de lo que has intentado, explicando el problema y el resultado deseado. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Es una mala práctica de HTML poner el mismo ID en dos o más elementos. Los elementos solo pueden tener un ID único por documento, si hay dos más ID iguales esto generará una excepción en el DOM.

Usa una clase en su lugar, no es necesario que la clase sea única, varios elementos pueden contener la misma clase.

Después explicado esto, puedes hacer esto de una manera simple con CSS:

```css
:target {
  border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
}

body, html {
  font-family:Arial;
  padding:20px;
}

a {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#news1">content 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="#news2">content 2</a></p>
    <p id="news1"><b>content 1...</b></p>
    <p id="news2"><b>content 2...</b></p>
  </body>
</html>
```