# Ejecutar función jquery más de una vez en php

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo este código, mediante el cual cargo la información que recojo de la base de datos y la muestro a través de un bucle foreach

```
<div class="contenedor">
     <div class="comentario d-flex flex-wrap">
           <div class="foto">
                <?php 
                 ?>
                 <img src="<?php foreach ($resultadoFoto as $key) {
                      echo $rutaSRC.$key -> fotoUsuario;}?>" width="100">
           </div>
           <div class="texto">
                <a href="conectLogin.php"><?php echo $usuario->getNombre()?></a>
                <p><?php echo $resultado -> titulo ?></p>
                <p class="texto-comentario"><?php echo $resultado -> descripcion ?></p>
           </div>
           <div class="botones d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap w-100">
                <button class="eliminar" id="borrarActividad"><i class="icono icon-cancel"></i>Eliminar</button>
           </div>
           </div>
           <?php
                }
           }
                                

           ?>
           </div>
```

En el botón de eliminar he añadido un id para poder ejecutar mediante jquery un modal en boostrap para que el usuario tenga la oportunidad de borrar la actividad seleccionada.

El problema me viene cuando trato de seleccionar alguna actividad de la lista distinta de la primera. la función de jquery sólo ejecuta el modal en la primera actividad de la lista, sin opción de escoger otra aleatoria.

Aquí mi código jquery

```
<script>
    $('#borrarActividad').on("click", function() {
        // do something
        $('#deleteActividad').modal('show');
    });

    $('#confirmarBorrado').on("click", function() {
        // do something
        $('#deleteActividad2').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
```

He mirado en la consola y si que veo que el resto de las actividades tienen asignado el id borrarActividad.

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute el modal de actividad más de una vez y donde yo quiera?

Muchas gracias por leerme

Comment: @Marcos hola, sí, está bien, he copiado únicamente el extracto donde está el botón de eliminar porque es un código largo y no quería saturar la pregunta, ya que en lo que tengo la duda es en ejecutar más de una vez el script jquery cuando pulso al botón eliminar.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/417888/16597)

Comment: @Marcos muchas gracias por tu aporte, ya me quedó claro y he entendido el porqué. He aplicado lo de la respuesta y ya me funciona :) Muchas gracias por ayudarme

Comment: @rilejon sería bueno que explicaras en una respuesta, cómo un código CSS te ayudó a solucionar tu problema con jQuery y el bucle PHP

Comment: ¿El título de esta pregunta es, sin duda, incorrecto. En realidad estás ejecutando algo en jQuery en PHP una vez y quieres que se ejecute más veces? En el uso normal, PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y jQuery en el cliente, por lo que habría manera ejecutar un jQuery desde PHP.

Comment: @JheymanMejia lo que hice para que me identificara el botón al que quería llamar, en lugar de por su id, fue a través de su clase `$('.borrar1').on("click", function() {
        // do something
        $('#deleteActividad').modal('show');
    });` y ya el script se ejecuta en función del botón que pulso.